# Cannot use associative keys with livewire to remove input fields from array

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a problem with a livewire not easy to explain, but I'll try my best.
Basically I'm doing a dynamic form with an array of key-value pairs from a serialized record.
The user should be able to add new fields and remove them.
The problem is the remove method, given that it doesn't seem to accept the key as parameter.
Any way I can handle this?
This is the livewire component:

```
class SetPositions extends Component
{
    protected $listeners = ['updatePositions' => 'render'];
    public $positions = [];
    public $key;
    public $value;
    public function mount(){
        $this->positions = Settings::where('name', '=', 'PEOPLE_POSITIONS')->pluck('value')->first();
    }

    public function addPosition() {
        $this->positions[$this->key] = $this->value;
        $this->emit('updatePositions');
    }

    public function removePosition($param){
        dd($param);
    }

    
    <form method="post" wire:submit.prevent="update">
            @csrf
            @method('PUT')
            @foreach($this->positions as $key => $value)
            <div x-data="{ block: false}" class="sm:grid sm:grid-cols-3 sm:gap-4 sm:items-start sm:border-t sm:border-gray-200 sm:pt-5">
                <div x-show="!block" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 sm:mt-px sm:pt-2">
                    <!--<input :disabled="!block" value="" type="text" class="block w-full max-w-lg border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:max-w-xs sm:text-sm">-->
                    <label for="test" class="block w-full max-w-lg border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:max-w-xs sm:text-sm">
                        {{$key}}
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div x-show="!block" class="mt-1 sm:mt-0 sm:col-span-1">
                    <input wire:model="positions.{{$key}}" type="text" class="block w-full max-w-lg border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:max-w-xs sm:text-sm">
                </div>
                <button wire:click="removePosition({{$positions[$key]}})" @click="block = !block" type="button">
                    <svg class="w-6 h-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12" />
                    </svg>
                </button>
            </div> 
            @endforeach
```

Comment: What do you mean by; "given that it doesn't seem to accept the key as parameter." Is the $param empty or does it throw a exception ?

Comment: Why are you passing `$positions[$key]` to the `removePosition` method? All that will do is pass `$value` effectively. You'd be better doing `removePosition({{ $key }})`, then removing that key, if it exists, from the `$positions` property

Comment: @frogeyedman $param returns an empty array

Comment: @JustCarty I've tried to pass both $key and $value. In the first case the method doesn't fire, in the second it returns an empty array.

Comment: I'll be honest, I think you need to start from scratch.  You'd be better off getting `$positions` from the Settings in the controller, then passing that to a view, then passing that into a `foreach ($settings as $setting)`, then passing that into a Livewire component that handles each one, one at a time. This will be a lot easier to control.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Laravel documentation for the pluck method. Right now you can handle positions property as an array with key-value pair
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-pluck